# ServiceStack: Writing an API without needing multiple DTOs?

Tags: servicestack

Subject may be unclear, but I'd like to expose two API calls that are almost identical, like so:

```
Routes
            .Add<GameConsole>("/consoles", "GET")
            .Add<GameConsole>("/consoles/count", "GET");
```

What I have now is "/consoles" giving me a list of all GameConsole objects from my repository. What I'd like to add is "/consoles/count", which gives me a count of all the GameConsole objects from my repository.

But since the service can only map one DTO in the routes, I can only have:

```
    public object Get(GameConsole request)
    {
        return mRepository.GetConsoles();
    }
```

Not sure I truly understand the limitations of only having one route map to a DTO; is there a way around this? As a side note, it seems odd that I have to pass the DTO to my service method, even though it's not being used at all (mapping to the route is the only purpose?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 2 routes don't contain any mappings to any variables and are both registered with the same request, you wont be able to tell the matching route from just the Request DTO, e.g:

```
public object Get(GameConsole request)
{
    return mRepository.GetConsoles();
}
```

i.e. You would need to introspect the **base.Request** and look at the .`PathInfo`, `RawUrl` or `AbsoluteUri` to distinguish the differences.

If it mapped to a variable, e.g:

```
Routes
  .Add<GameConsole>("/consoles", "GET")
  .Add<GameConsole>("/consoles/{Action}", "GET");
```

Then you can distinguish the requests by looking at the populated `request.Action`.

But if they have different behaviors and return different responses then they should just be 2 separate services, e.g:

```
Routes
  .Add<GameConsole>("/consoles", "GET")
  .Add<GameConsoleCount>("/consoles/count", "GET");
```

The other option is to only have a single coarse-grained service that returns the combined dataset of both services (i.e. that also contains the count) that way the same service can fulfill both requests.

Comment: Thanks mythz. In your example of adding the /consoles/{Action} route and then looking at the request.Action, this doesn't work for me. I get a "Unable to bind request" RequestBindingException. My Routes and Get handler look exactly as they do in my original post, and the URL I'm trying is, http://localhost:7777/consoles/count. A breakpoint is never hit in my Get handler. Any ideas?

Comment: `{Action}` is a placeholder for any public property on your Request DTO. i.e. Add `public string Action { get; set; }` to your `GameConsole` Request DTO if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks so much, mythz. Great framework btw. I most definitely like its simplicity over WCF. I am trying to find uses for it over MVC's web api now.

Answer (score 0):

In very similar situations, I have been creating a subclass DTO for each separate routing service, inheriting the shared elements.

It has been working very well.

So the pattern is

```
  public class SharedRequestDto 
  {
      public string CommonItem { set; get; }
      public string CommonId   { set; get; }
  }
```

then

```
  [Route("/api/mainservice")]
  public class MainServiceRequest : SharedRequestedDto 
  {
  }

  [Route("/api/similarservice")]
  public class SimilarServiceRquest : SharedRequestDto
  {
      public string AddedItem { set; get; }
  }
```

This allows differing but similar DTOs to be routed to individual services to process them.  There is no need to perform introspection.

You can still use common code when necessary behind the concrete services because they can assume that their request object parameter is a `SharedRequestDto`.

It probably is not the right solution for every use case, but it is effective, especially since many of my DTOs are in families that share a great deal of data.